# Abrir página usando navegador externo

Tags: html5, angularjs, visual-studio-2015

Olá estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com o framework OnsenUi (Cordova no visual studio)
Mas o código abaixo abre a url usando o próprio aplicativo como browser. No fim das contas ao fazer isso ,se eu precisar usar o alicativo , tenho que abrir ele novamente pois ele abre a url pelo próprio app. Ou seja ele transforma o aplicativo em um browser. Como eu poderia  acessar a url chamando um browser externo ou abrir uma outra tela, sem comprometer o uso do aplicativo?

```
  <ons-icon icon="fa fa-globe" fixed-width="true" onclick="location.href ='http://www.meusite.com.br'"></ons-icon>
```

eu encontrei essa solução mas não consegui aplicar até o momento. Eu ja adicionei o plugin InAppBrowser ao projeto

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091912/i-need-to-launch-an-external-website-in-onsen-ui/34102792

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim : Lembrando que adicionei InappBrowser

```
<ons-icon icon="fa fa-globe" fixed-width="true" onclick="window.open('http://www.meusite.com.br', '_blank', 'location=yes')"></ons-icon>
```